# "null" not allowed in package name

Tags: java, java-package

I want to create a java package name where one of the elements is the word "null".

Java tells me this is not a valid package:

```
package org.null.thing;

public class Foo { 
  public static int addThing(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error: <identifier> expected
package org.null.thing;
            ^
```

Where is this defined? What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that null is simply not allowed as "[identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)":

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter. An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean literal (§3.10.3), or the null literal (§3.10.7).

Thus `org.null.thing` is as invalid as `or.int.string` or other interesting ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I just realised at the very moment you replied :)

Comment: Fine with me ... you got an answer, I got an upvote. I can live with that ;-)

Comment: Actually, `null` is not and cannot be an identifier, which is rather the point of the cited passage.

Comment: @LewBloch Correct. Reworded accordingly.